# Finding x when sin(x) = -.758

Tags: functions

I'm not understanding how to find all the angles for when sin(x) is equated to a negative decimal can someone explain to me how to find it..? So far I came up with 49.288 degrees, and 229.288 degree. I'm not sure if I'm doing this properly or not..

Comment: In Mathematica, `Reduce[Sin[x] == -.758, x] or Reduce[Sin[x] == -758/1000, x]

Comment: `ArcSin[-0.758]` will give you an answer in radians.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1):

ArcSin[x] returns the angle `a` between `-Pi/2` and `Pi/2`  radians such that `Sin[a] = x` .

If we want values in another interval or in Degrees we need a conversion.

```
f[x_] := Module[{answer},
    If[x < 0,
answer = {\[Pi] - ArcSin[x], 2 \[Pi] + ArcSin[x]} ,
answer = {ArcSin[x], \[Pi] - ArcSin[x]} ];
Map[DMSString, answer/Degree]
]


x = -0.758;
f[x]
{"229 17'17.51329", "310\[Degree]42'42.48671"}

f[-x]
{"49\[Degree]17'17.51329", "130\[Degree]42'42.48671"}
```

(I definitely need to learn how write here in a more beautiful way, please send comments to garciacapitan@gmail.com)

Comment: Regarding your parenthetical have you seen [editing help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)?